# Smile ElasticSuite Curl Error In DataDog When Deleting Indexes With _bulk

Tags: php, curl, magento2, datadog

I'm experiencing a really odd issue, when placing an order in magento 2.4 using elasticsuite 2.11.2 data dog is reporting "CURL request failure" when it runs the indexing update to the _bulk endpoint.

The strange thing about this is that the curl requests return 200 response, and there are no errors in the magento logs or php logs, so i don't know where datadog is getting this from.

This is the trace from datadog:

```
curl error: CURL request failure
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Client/CurlMultiHandler.php(134): curl_multi_exec()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(127): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlMultiHandler->execute()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(58): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->invokeWait()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(127): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->wait()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(58): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->invokeWait()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/MagicFutureTrait.php(30): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->wait()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/FutureArray.php(27): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->__get()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/Index/AsyncIndexOperation.php(113): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->offsetGet()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/Index/AsyncIndexOperation.php(130): Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Index\AsyncIndexOperation->resolveFutureBulks()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/Indexer/GenericIndexerHandler.php(128): Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Index\AsyncIndexOperation->refreshIndex()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(221): Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Indexer\GenericIndexerHandler->saveIndex()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(198): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->processBatch()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(152): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeByDimensions()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(250): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->execute()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeList()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callParent()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(533): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->executeList()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(294): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexList()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Plugin/Indexer/AbstractIndexerPlugin.php(67): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexList()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Plugin/Indexer/Stock/ReindexProductsAfterStockUpdate.php(93): Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Plugin\Indexer\AbstractIndexerPlugin->processFullTextIndex()
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Plugin\Indexer\Stock\ReindexProductsAfterStockUpdate->aroundExecuteList()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/Indexer/Stock/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(533): Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Interceptor->executeList()
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(294): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexList()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/AbstractProcessor.php(69): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexList()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Observer/ReindexQuoteInventoryObserver.php(84): Magento\Framework\Indexer\AbstractProcessor->reindexList()
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\ReindexQuoteInventoryObserver->execute()
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()
#32 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch()
```

I've been through the code with xdebug and i see no curl errors at all, i do see responses from elastic with 404 where a document does not exist in an index, but this surely wouldn't cause a curl error when the http response is 200. It just doesn't make any sense.